# a xib doesn't fit to the display

Tags: ios, xcode8, xib

a xib doesn't fit to the display.

Although I made it like this,

[xib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Kqd.png)

if I run my project, it shows like this.

[display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Uj7f.jpg)

Do you have any ideas about this problem?

Thanks in advance for any helps.

Comment: Hi @Yutaro, did you setup your constraints? If so, can you provide a screenshot of it?

Comment: Thanks for commenting! the screenshot is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo3OU.png

Comment: @Yutaro have used clipsToBound on the imageView in the cell plus you should restrain the imageView using the aspectRatio constraint.